# redux change prop based on form input

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a form like this:

```
class SuperSignupScreenImpl extends React.PureComponent<SuperSignupScreenProps & {dispatch: Dispatch<{}>}, {}> {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <TextField
                hintText = "Name"
                onChange = {this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
                name = "name"
            >

                </TextField>
               <p>{this.props.name}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    handleInputChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        console.log(value);
        this.props.dispatch(updateForm(name, value));
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state: {name: string[]}): SuperSignupScreenProps {
    return {name: state.name};
}

const SuperSignupScreen = connect(mapStateToProps)(SuperSignupScreenImpl);

export default SuperSignupScreen;
```

And the actions-reducers look like this:

```
export type SuperSignupScreenProps = {name: string[]};
export const updateForm = (field: string, value: string) => (dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => {
    var arr = [value];
    dispatch(setName(arr));
};
export const setName = createAction('SET_NAME', (name: string[]) => name);

export const setNameReducer = handleAction(setName, (state, action) => action.payload, [] as string[]);

export const superSignupReducer = combineReducers({
    setNameFunc: setNameReducer
});
```

When run this code does not show the entered name in the `<p>` tag.

What am I missing here?
Also what is a better way of checking if the props are being updated properly?

Comment: btw for typescript there are brilliant typescript-fsa libraries to keep actions and reducers clean. regarding your question, what do you see in redux dev util? Does it trigger actions?

Comment: I don't see where you injected the name as props. Where is your mapStateToProps?

Comment: @nbkhope I forgot that to add here..done..please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are firing the action incorrectly.

In order for Redux to know that the action you're calling should affect the store, **it needs to be connected to the component just like your state**.

## Try mapping your actions to props first.

Something along these lines should do the trick (see the comments for more detail):

```
// Change this to reference the file that exports your updateForm action
import { updateForm } from '/actions/form';

class SuperSignupScreenImpl extends React.PureComponent<SuperSignupScreenProps & {dispatch: Dispatch<{}>}, {}> {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <TextField
          hintText = "Name"
          onChange = {this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
          name = "name"
        >

        </TextField>
        <p>{this.props.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleInputChange(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log(value);
    // use your action like this (now that it's mapped to this component's props)
    this.props.updateForm(name, value);
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state: {name: string[]}): SuperSignupScreenProps {
  return {name: state.name};
}
// map the updateForm action we imported above
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
  return {updateForm};
}

// and connect it here
const SuperSignupScreen = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SuperSignupScreenImpl);

export default SuperSignupScreen;
```

**If you need additional reference**, check out the way I've hooked this up in my TypeScript React/Redux boilerplate. I'd start here and work your way out:

https://github.com/jonnyasmar/gravity-bp/blob/master/src/utils/redux.ts

Comment: I tried this, but the updateForm function is not called..why?